# Prove that a binary language is not regular by using the fact that the binary language of palindromes is not regular without using Pumping Lemma.

Tags: regular-language

**Note:** This is not a repeat question. There is another questions very similar to this posted, but that uses the Pumping Lemma.

> A binary language of all binary strings that are palindromes $L_1$ is not regular. Use this fact to prove that $L_2$ which contains all binary strings that are not palindromes is not regular. Prove this **without** using Pumping Lemma.

Comment: You’ve omitted an absolutely essential piece of information: what is the language $L_2$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott L2 is a binary language of any binary string that is not a palindrome.

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site, not a place to copy-paste an exercise-style problem statement and expect someone to solve it for you.  As such, you must articulate a specific question.  I don't see a question here, just a demand for someone to do a task for you (and that's not appropriate).  Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/14578 and edit your question accordingly, including to provide *context* as described there.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $L_2$ were regular, there would be a DFA $M$ that recognized (accepted) it. Explain how to modify $M$ so that it would recognize $L_1$. Since $L_1$ is not regular, that’s impossible, and the contradiction will prove that $L_2$ can’t be regular.